# Design view to drag and drop controls on html with Netbeans?

Tags: html, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.0 on Windows and I'm working on an html file.

Does Netbeans have a Design View for html files so you can drag and drop controls like buttons and textboxes?

I only see the source View.

If it has a design View, how do I enable it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It doesn't, but you can use some UI frameworks to code easier your html like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).